# How can I transfer my score from one activity to another on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

This is how I used my integer from one activity. It's a matching type question and the corresponding radio button is one of the answers. The correct radiobutton would give the score of 1.

```
Integer score1;
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int rb1) {
  switch(rb1){
  case R.id.radioButton1:
     score1=0;
     break;
  case R.id.radioButton2:
     score1=0;
     break;
  case R.id.radioButton3:
     score1=0;
     break;  
  case R.id.radioButton4:
     score1= 1;
     break;  
}
```

On the result screen I will be usng the integer like this:

```
totalscore = score1 +score2 .....
```

How do I transfer `score1` from the activity with the radio buttons to the activity for the result screen?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Integer score1, totalscore;

public void onCheckedChange(RadioGroup group, int rb1) {
    switch (rb1) {
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            score1=0;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            score1=0;
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            score1=0;
            break;  
        case R.id.radioButton4:
            score1= 1;
            totalscore += 1;
            break;  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can greatly simplify your `switch` logic:

```
Integer score1;
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int rb1) {
    score1 = (rb1 == R.id.radioButton4) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Second, there are several different ways to pass `score1` from one Activity to another.  For instance, when you create your `Intent` for the second Activity, you can use `putExtra()` to store your score value, and then the second Activity can use `getExtra()` to read the value when it starts.

Or you can use any of a number of quick but questionable hacks, such as making `score1` a `public static` field, or passing it around via system properties, or writing it out to an agreed-upon file location, or storing it to an agreed-upon field in a database (these hacks only work if there is only a single instance of your activity per device, and are really not recommended at all).

Really though you should just stick with `getExtra()` and `putExtra()`.  Along the lines of:

```
//in QuestionActivity
private Integer score1;

//...

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int rb1) {
    score1 = (rb1 == R.id.radioButton4) ? 1 : 0;
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("score1", score1);
    startActivity(resultIntent);
}


//in ResultActivity
private Integer score1;

//...

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    score1 = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score1");
    super.onStart();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really made my coding simple. Now how can I use the putextra and get extra again using this score1 and how will I use it on my second screen when I will be applying it as totalscore=score1+score2+score3.... my first activity is question1 and my second activity is resultscreen. thanks again.